# Please stop [abuse]ing this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Yet another burnination request (*if you couldn't tell by the title you haven't been here long enough*)...

---

**Today's culprit:** The [abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abuse) tag

**Stats:** 35 questions (Update 10 June 2022: 20 questions), only five visible questions in the last two years (although I'm sure there's many that have been removed - I've seen Meta discussions about questions with this tag). Somewhat of a tag wiki.

---

#### Burnination Questions

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied, and is it unambiguous?**

   It does somewhat describe the contents of the questions (some sort of mis-use of something), but it is completely ambiguous and can refer to literally any programming language. Also, when "abuse" occurs is case-by-case and determined by the user.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   No. It does not refer to a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, a software tool, or a topic that is unique to software development.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   I would say no here - the tag covers a wide range of issues, and I've seen it used every time in a different case. One question referenced abusing `globals` in Perl, but it didn't need the tag - the question wasn't even about abuse, it was just added because the question mentioned abusing `globals` (only once).
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Edited: After seeing some responses, I'm changing my answer to a no for this  question. Robert Columbia [covered this pretty nicely in his response](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385453).

---

Leave your thoughts about whether or not this tag should be burninated down below. While many of the questions on the tag are actually good questions (above zero score), I think the majority of the questions could use more specific abuse tags, such as [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security) (which could be more appropriate than [abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abuse) in some cases). We'll have to figure out specific re-tagging contenders in the future to make the burnination successful.

**Edit:** Also, [misuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/misuse) is a good related tag. One user in the comments has proposed abolishing [abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abuse) and expanding [misuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/misuse).

Comment: Given the existence of the [`misuse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/misuse) tag, it's hard to see what more the `abuse` tag offers. How would one differentiate them? — On the other hand, the definition of `misuse` tag seems unnecessarily restrictive. What about programming situations where one deliberately misuses a language or framework feature in order to accomplish some tricky goal? I'm sure we've all done this. So I'd say: abolish `abuse` and broaden `misuse`.

Comment: @matt That's a good idea, I didn't previously see `misuse`. I edited my post.

Comment: I think you made all the right points in your post. Any valid use of this tag would be better served by a tag with more specific meaning. Burninate it.

Comment: `misuse` can come from lack of understanding, but `abuse` always implies malicious behaviour, so the two are not the same thing.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Not necessarily on your second point - what about ethical hacking? That's a form of abuse, but not malicious.

Comment: I wouldn't describe 'ethical hacking' as 'abuse' under any circumstances.

Answer (score 18):

For your last question, I'd say that it *doesn't* mean the same thing in all common contexts. There really are two different forms of "abuse" being spoken of in the tagged questions:

- Socially abusive uses of software, i.e. "bad hacking" ("cracking", "haxoring", etc.), and similar antisocial behaviors such as spamming, DDOSing, and otherwise using software in such a way as to violate Terms of Use, an Acceptable Use Policy, applicable law, or social mores.
- Technically abusive uses of software, i.e. "good hacking" - using software or tools in socially positive or at least neutral manners, but in ways not intended by the authors of such software or tools. This could include creative exercises such as writing a COBOL interpreter in T-SQL or [using highly creative HTML color names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8318911/6471538).

Comment: That's a good point - I didn't really consider the so-called "*good*" abuse or non-malicious types of abuse. I'm going to edit my post.

Comment: @connectyourcharger: And indeed the tagged questions use it both ways.